# How is support vectors arranged in Libsvm model?

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, svm, libsvm, supervised-learning

I would like to use the parameters derived from Libsvm model to predict new data (not in matlab). I want to ask whether the support vectors (nSV, sv_coef, SVs) in model are arranged according to the order of Label in the model? Below is the model derived from fisheriris using linear kernel, Label is [3;2;1] so does that mean nSV, sv_coef, SVs are in the order of [class3;class2;class1]?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes indeed. I've been doing a similar experiment and my results are

[image]

It looks like the first three SVs are from class 1. From the SV indices field I've got

[image]

and by looking at such indices into the label vector I've got:

[image]
[image]

The 24th, 25th and 42nd patterns indeed have label 1.

The 4th SV indices is 53 which has, as instead, label 2...and so on.

Comment: Thank you! and also... If I do binary classification, for example, nSV=[25;24], Label=[2;1], sv_coef should be devided to 2 parts (first 25 instances represent coef of class2 vs class1 and latter 24 instances represent coef of class1 vs class2). When calculate decision value of class2 vs class1, I should use z*svs'*coef-rho(z is new data sample), however when calculate decision value of class1 vs class2 (i.e. use the latter part of sv_coef), should I use z*svs'*coef-rho or z*svs'*coef+rho(z is new data sample)...?

Comment: Can I be honest with you? There's no need for such calculations in LibSVM. By using the command `-b 1` in both `svmtrain()` and `svmpredict()`, LibSVM automatically evaluates the decision values for you. In particular, the decision values will be the third output from `svmpredict()`, which you can call as `[PredictedLabels, Accuracy, DecisionValues]=svmpredict(ValidationLabels,ValidationSet,SVMmodel,'-b 1')`

Comment: yes yes I know that :D But I need to do the prediction part outside matlab... which means I need to use the parameters that the model gives me to reconstruct the equation somewhere else (in java for example)

Comment: have a look at this answer here: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/126379/libsvm-on-matlab-with-rbf-kernel-compute-distance-from-hyperplane